# Absolute children in overflow

Tags: css

The problem i have is that i need to achieve what i have below where "DROPDOWN" breaks outside the container but his parent is not position: absolute because then it breaks the structure of the inner scroll. How can i make Dropdown break the boundries of the scroll container + not have a absolute parent without using javascript?

```css
#W {
  overflow-x: visible;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#c {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#max-parent {
  position: absolute;
}


#abs-p {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

#abs-c {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="w">
  <div id="c">
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div id="max-parent">
      <div id="abs-p">
      <div id="abs-c">
        Dropdown
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>
    <div>HELLO</div>                                                     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use position:relative for element with id #c - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vRKdXQ

Comment: Sorry, you're codepen isn't working i need Dropdown to BREAK the boundries of the scroll bar (i.e overflow-x visible) BUT without the need for his parent to be positioned absolutely.

Comment: to reword the issue in a more understandable way:
Dropdown must be overflow-x visibled | AND | "max-parent" can't be position: absolute, because it stuffs up the structure of the inner scroll elements.

Comment: width of dropdown should fit the width of red background dropdown

Comment: can you give a fiddle please naga? to show @NagaSaiA

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/s4s858d1/1/

Comment: @NagaSaiA sorry naga the problem is i need "dropdown" to BREAK the boundries of the scroll as per the original example but WITHOUT max-parent being position absolute

Comment: at what position , are you looking for max-parent, any screenshot or rough sketch how it should look?

Comment: max-parent not position absolute
dropdown should still break out of scroll box